# check if timestamp between 2 dates

Tags: go

I have dates stored as timestamps in mongo, for example, `1564444800000000000`. I want to check if a timestamp is between 2 dates - July 1, 2021 and July, 2021. I converted these 2 dates to timestamps using https://www.epochconverter.com/. I first fetched all records and while looping through the records, I did a check like so

```
cDate := 1564444800000000000
if  cDate > 1625167488000 &&  cDate <  1627759488000 {
        log.Fatal("found one!")
}
```

But this not seem to work as I get no matches. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to transform in a date then check with the before and after API, as example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    cDate := int64(1564444800000000000)
    firstJuly := time.Date(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    thrirtyOneJuly := time.Date(2019, 7, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

    date := time.Unix(0, cDate)
    // fmt.Println(date) //will print 2019-07-30 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
    fmt.Println("Is July?", date.After(firstJuly) && date.Before(thrirtyOneJuly))
}
```

will print

```
Is July? true
```

[See on playground](https://go.dev/play/p/klQJDWcZMS8)

Answer (score 4):

I mean just looking at the numbers:

```
cDate := 1564444800000000000
               1625167488000
               1627759488000
```

I don't see how one with six more digits than the one's it's supposed to be between would ever be between them.  And even if we divided `CDate` by `1000000` it would be

```
cDate := 1564444800000
         1625167488000
         1627759488000
```

and it's still less than both of those, so it still wouldn't be between them.  But that being said, you most likely do just need to divide `cDate` by `1000000` and your example is just not a good one (since 1564444800000 is July 29 2019)